# Deployment of C# app which connects to Oracle database

Tags: java, .net, oracle

simple question here. If I develop an app in C# which connects to Oracle, I need to have oracle client installed on the client machine. My questions are :

1. Do I have to install the full client (or Instant client), or I can deploy just few dlls with my C# app ?
2. Same question but not for C# but for Java app. Is the Oracle client required there ? Can I simply deploy few dlls instead of installing the full client ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From poking around on the Oracle site, it looks like what you want is the "[Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html)" download.

Comment: I think Instant Client does not include the odp.net provider